# Migrate customer data from magento 1.9 to magento-2?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

How to migrate customer data from magento 1.9 to magento-2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [magento2 Own data migration tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-overview-practices.html) to migrate data from  magento1 to Magento2.

There are 3 steps in migration:

```
 1. Setting 
 2. Data 
 3. Delta
```

In  step2, main Data like customers, orders, products etc. will migrate.

Please check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-migrate-data.html for more details.